# Javascript on change text animation restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, web

I am new in Javascript. I have a text animation on a web page, that should be restarted when text will be changed in it. I am changing the text with the call from Android, and the web page should get updated automatically. When I change the plain text, it gets updated, but doesn't work for animation script. 
I wonder, if you need some kind of a listener in a web page, so you can catch the change of a text by id and restart the animation. Or maybe not. Couldn't figure out, how to restart it. 
Thanks in advance.

This is my HTML Code:

```js
(function ($) {
  "use strict"; 

  function isInEffect (effect) {
    return /In/.test(effect) || $.inArray(effect, $.fn.textillate.defaults.inEffects) >= 0;
  };

  // custom get data api method
  function getData (node) {
    var attrs = node.attributes || []
    , data = {};

    if (!attrs.length) return data;

    $.each(attrs, function (i, attr) {
      var nodeName = attr.nodeName.replace(/delayscale/, 'delayScale');
      if (/^data-in-*/.test(nodeName)) {
        data.in = data.in || {};
        data.in[nodeName.replace(/data-in-/, '')] = stringToBoolean(attr.nodeValue);
      } else if (/^data-out-*/.test(nodeName)) {
        data.out = data.out || {};
        data.out[nodeName.replace(/data-out-/, '')] =stringToBoolean(attr.nodeValue);
      } else if (/^data-*/.test(nodeName)) {
        data[nodeName.replace(/data-/, '')] = stringToBoolean(attr.nodeValue);
      }
    })

    return data;
  }

  function animate ($c, effect, cb) {
    $c.addClass('animated ' + effect)
    .css('visibility', 'visible')
    .show();

    $c.one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function () {
      $c.removeClass('animated ' + effect);
      cb && cb();
    });
  }

  function animateChars ($chars, options, cb) {
    var that = this
    , count = $chars.length;

    if (!count) {
      cb && cb();
      return;
    } 

    if (options.shuffle) $chars = shuffle($chars);
    if (options.reverse) $chars = $chars.toArray().reverse();

    $.each($chars, function (i, c) {
      var $char = $(c);

      function complete () {
        if (isInEffect(options.effect)) {
          $char.css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else if (isOutEffect(options.effect)) {
          $char.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        count -= 1;
        if (!count && cb) cb();
      }

      var delay = options.sync ? options.delay : options.delay * i * options.delayScale;

      $char.text() ? 
        setTimeout(function () { animate($char, options.effect, complete) }, delay) :
      complete();
    });
  };

  var Textillate = function (element, options) {
    var base = this
    , $element = $(element);

    base.init = function () {
      base.$texts = $element.find(options.selector);

      if (!base.$texts.length) {
        base.$texts = $('<ul class="texts"><li>' + $element.html() + '</li></ul>');
        $element.html(base.$texts);
      }

      base.$texts.hide();

      base.$current = $('<span>')
      .text(base.$texts.find(':first-child').html())
      .prependTo($element);

      if (isInEffect(options.in.effect)) {
        base.$current.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      } else if (isOutEffect(options.out.effect)) {
        base.$current.css('visibility', 'visible');
      }

      base.setOptions(options);

      base.timeoutRun = null;

      setTimeout(function () {
        base.options.autoStart && base.start();
      }, base.options.initialDelay)
    };

    base.setOptions = function (options) {
      base.options = options;
    };

    base.triggerEvent = function (name) {
      var e = $.Event(name + '.tlt');
      $element.trigger(e, base);
      return e;
    };

    base.in = function (index, cb) {
      index = index || 0;

      var $elem = base.$texts.find(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')')
      , options = $.extend(true, {}, base.options, $elem.length ? getData($elem[0]) : {})
      , $chars;

      $elem.addClass('current');

      base.triggerEvent('inAnimationBegin');

      base.$current
      .text($elem.html())
      .lettering('words');

      base.$current.find('[class^="word"]')
      .css({ 
        'display': 'inline-block',
        // fix for poor ios performance
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
        '-o-transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
        'transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
      })
      .each(function () { $(this).lettering() });

      $chars = base.$current
      .find('[class^="char"]')
      .css('display', 'inline-block');

      if (isInEffect(options.in.effect)) {
        $chars.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      } else if (isOutEffect(options.in.effect)) {
        $chars.css('visibility', 'visible');
      }

      base.currentIndex = index;

      animateChars($chars, options.in, function () {
        base.triggerEvent('inAnimationEnd');
        if (options.in.callback) options.in.callback();
        if (cb) cb(base);
      });
    };

    base.start = function (index) {
      base.triggerEvent('start');

      (function run (index) {
        base.in(index, function () {
          var length = base.$texts.children().length;

          index += 1;

          if (!base.options.loop && index >= length) {
            if (base.options.callback) base.options.callback();
            base.triggerEvent('end');
          } else {
            index = index % length;

            base.timeoutRun = setTimeout(function () {
              base.out(function () {
                run(index)
              });
            }, base.options.minDisplayTime);
          }
        });
      }(index || 0));
    };

    base.stop = function () {
      if (base.timeoutRun) {
        clearInterval(base.timeoutRun);
        base.timeoutRun = null;
      }
    };

    base.init();
  }

  $.fn.textillate = function (settings, args) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      , data = $this.data('textillate')
      , options = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.textillate.defaults, getData(this), typeof settings == 'object' && settings);

      if (!data) { 
        $this.data('textillate', (data = new Textillate(this, options)));
      } else if (typeof settings == 'string') {
        data[settings].apply(data, [].concat(args));
      } else {
        data.setOptions.call(data, options);
      }
    })
  };

  $.fn.textillate.defaults = {
    selector: '.texts',
    loop: false,
    minDisplayTime: 2000,
    initialDelay: 0,
    in: {
      effect: 'fadeInLeftBig',
      delayScale: 1.5,
      delay: 50,
      sync: false,
      reverse: false,
      shuffle: false,
      callback: function () {}
    },
    out: {
      effect: 'hinge',
      delayScale: 1.5,
      delay: 50,
      sync: false,
      reverse: false,
      shuffle: false,
      callback: function () {}
    },
    autoStart: true,
    inEffects: [],
    outEffects: [ 'hinge' ],
    callback: function () {}
  };

}(jQuery));

// Lettering.js

(function($){
  function injector(t, splitter, klass, after) {
    var a = t.text().split(splitter), inject = '';
    if (a.length) {
      $(a).each(function(i, item) {
        inject += '<span class="'+klass+(i+1)+'">'+item+'</span>'+after;
      }); 
      t.empty().append(inject);
    }
  }

  var methods = {
    init : function() {

      return this.each(function() {
        injector($(this), '', 'char', '');
      });

    },

    words : function() {

      return this.each(function() {
        injector($(this), ' ', 'word', ' ');
      });

    },

    lines : function() {

      return this.each(function() {
        var r = "eefec303079ad17405c889e092e105b0";
        // Because it's hard to split a <br/> tag consistently across browsers,
        // (*ahem* IE *ahem*), we replaces all <br/> instances with an md5 hash 
        // (of the word "split").  If you're trying to use this plugin on that 
        // md5 hash string, it will fail because you're being ridiculous.
        injector($(this).children("br").replaceWith(r).end(), r, 'line', '');
      });

    }
  };

  $.fn.lettering = function( method ) {
    // Method calling logic
    if ( method && methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( method === 'letters' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 0 ) ); // always pass an array
    }
    $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.lettering' );
    return this;
  };

})(jQuery);
// Fittext.js

(function( $ ){

  $.fn.fitText = function( kompressor, options ) {

    // Setup options
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
        settings = $.extend({
          'minFontSize' : Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
          'maxFontSize' : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        }, options);

    return this.each(function(){

      // Store the object
      var $this = $(this); 

      // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
      var resizer = function () {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };

      // Call once to set.
      resizer();

      // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
      $(window).on('resize', resizer);
    });

  };

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Welcome page</title>
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="jumbotron"id="title">
  <h1 class="glow in tlt" id="helloworld" >Hello</h1>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<script>
  setTimeout( function() {
    $(function (){
      $('.jumbotron h1')
      .fitText(0.8)
      .textillate({ in: { effect: 'flipInY' }});
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('h1.glow').removeClass('in');
      }, 2000);
    });
  }, 1000 );
</script>
```

Textillate.js

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict"; 

  function isInEffect (effect) {
    return /In/.test(effect) || $.inArray(effect, $.fn.textillate.defaults.inEffects) >= 0;
  };

  // custom get data api method
  function getData (node) {
    var attrs = node.attributes || []
      , data = {};

    if (!attrs.length) return data;

    $.each(attrs, function (i, attr) {
      var nodeName = attr.nodeName.replace(/delayscale/, 'delayScale');
      if (/^data-in-*/.test(nodeName)) {
        data.in = data.in || {};
        data.in[nodeName.replace(/data-in-/, '')] = stringToBoolean(attr.nodeValue);
      } else if (/^data-out-*/.test(nodeName)) {
        data.out = data.out || {};
        data.out[nodeName.replace(/data-out-/, '')] =stringToBoolean(attr.nodeValue);
      } else if (/^data-*/.test(nodeName)) {
        data[nodeName.replace(/data-/, '')] = stringToBoolean(attr.nodeValue);
      }
    })

    return data;
  }

  function animate ($c, effect, cb) {
    $c.addClass('animated ' + effect)
      .css('visibility', 'visible')
      .show();

    $c.one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function () {
        $c.removeClass('animated ' + effect);
        cb && cb();
    });
  }

  function animateChars ($chars, options, cb) {
    var that = this
      , count = $chars.length;

    if (!count) {
      cb && cb();
      return;
    } 

    if (options.shuffle) $chars = shuffle($chars);
    if (options.reverse) $chars = $chars.toArray().reverse();

    $.each($chars, function (i, c) {
      var $char = $(c);

      function complete () {
        if (isInEffect(options.effect)) {
          $char.css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else if (isOutEffect(options.effect)) {
          $char.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        count -= 1;
        if (!count && cb) cb();
      }

      var delay = options.sync ? options.delay : options.delay * i * options.delayScale;

      $char.text() ? 
        setTimeout(function () { animate($char, options.effect, complete) }, delay) :
        complete();
    });
  };

  var Textillate = function (element, options) {
    var base = this
      , $element = $(element);

    base.init = function () {
      base.$texts = $element.find(options.selector);

      if (!base.$texts.length) {
        base.$texts = $('<ul class="texts"><li>' + $element.html() + '</li></ul>');
        $element.html(base.$texts);
      }

      base.$texts.hide();

      base.$current = $('<span>')
        .text(base.$texts.find(':first-child').html())
        .prependTo($element);

      if (isInEffect(options.in.effect)) {
        base.$current.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      } else if (isOutEffect(options.out.effect)) {
        base.$current.css('visibility', 'visible');
      }

      base.setOptions(options);

      base.timeoutRun = null;

      setTimeout(function () {
        base.options.autoStart && base.start();
      }, base.options.initialDelay)
    };

    base.setOptions = function (options) {
      base.options = options;
    };

    base.triggerEvent = function (name) {
      var e = $.Event(name + '.tlt');
      $element.trigger(e, base);
      return e;
    };

    base.in = function (index, cb) {
      index = index || 0;

      var $elem = base.$texts.find(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')')
        , options = $.extend(true, {}, base.options, $elem.length ? getData($elem[0]) : {})
        , $chars;

      $elem.addClass('current');

      base.triggerEvent('inAnimationBegin');

      base.$current
        .text($elem.html())
        .lettering('words');

      base.$current.find('[class^="word"]')
          .css({ 
            'display': 'inline-block',
            // fix for poor ios performance
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
               '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
                 '-o-transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
                    'transform': 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
          })
          .each(function () { $(this).lettering() });

      $chars = base.$current
        .find('[class^="char"]')
        .css('display', 'inline-block');

      if (isInEffect(options.in.effect)) {
        $chars.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      } else if (isOutEffect(options.in.effect)) {
        $chars.css('visibility', 'visible');
      }

      base.currentIndex = index;

      animateChars($chars, options.in, function () {
        base.triggerEvent('inAnimationEnd');
        if (options.in.callback) options.in.callback();
        if (cb) cb(base);
      });
    };

    base.start = function (index) {
      base.triggerEvent('start');

      (function run (index) {
        base.in(index, function () {
          var length = base.$texts.children().length;

          index += 1;

          if (!base.options.loop && index >= length) {
            if (base.options.callback) base.options.callback();
            base.triggerEvent('end');
          } else {
            index = index % length;

            base.timeoutRun = setTimeout(function () {
              base.out(function () {
                run(index)
              });
            }, base.options.minDisplayTime);
          }
        });
      }(index || 0));
    };

    base.stop = function () {
      if (base.timeoutRun) {
        clearInterval(base.timeoutRun);
        base.timeoutRun = null;
      }
    };

    base.init();
  }

  $.fn.textillate = function (settings, args) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('textillate')
        , options = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.textillate.defaults, getData(this), typeof settings == 'object' && settings);

      if (!data) { 
        $this.data('textillate', (data = new Textillate(this, options)));
      } else if (typeof settings == 'string') {
        data[settings].apply(data, [].concat(args));
      } else {
        data.setOptions.call(data, options);
      }
    })
  };

  $.fn.textillate.defaults = {
    selector: '.texts',
    loop: false,
    minDisplayTime: 2000,
    initialDelay: 0,
    in: {
      effect: 'fadeInLeftBig',
      delayScale: 1.5,
      delay: 50,
      sync: false,
      reverse: false,
      shuffle: false,
      callback: function () {}
    },
    out: {
      effect: 'hinge',
      delayScale: 1.5,
      delay: 50,
      sync: false,
      reverse: false,
      shuffle: false,
      callback: function () {}
    },
    autoStart: true,
    inEffects: [],
    outEffects: [ 'hinge' ],
    callback: function () {}
  };

}(jQuery));
```

Lettering.js

```
(function($){
    function injector(t, splitter, klass, after) {
        var a = t.text().split(splitter), inject = '';
        if (a.length) {
            $(a).each(function(i, item) {
                inject += '<span class="'+klass+(i+1)+'">'+item+'</span>'+after;
            }); 
            t.empty().append(inject);
        }
    }

    var methods = {
        init : function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                injector($(this), '', 'char', '');
            });

        },

        words : function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                injector($(this), ' ', 'word', ' ');
            });

        },

        lines : function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                var r = "eefec303079ad17405c889e092e105b0";
                // Because it's hard to split a <br/> tag consistently across browsers,
                // (*ahem* IE *ahem*), we replaces all <br/> instances with an md5 hash 
                // (of the word "split").  If you're trying to use this plugin on that 
                // md5 hash string, it will fail because you're being ridiculous.
                injector($(this).children("br").replaceWith(r).end(), r, 'line', '');
            });

        }
    };

    $.fn.lettering = function( method ) {
        // Method calling logic
        if ( method && methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( method === 'letters' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 0 ) ); // always pass an array
        }
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.lettering' );
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Fittext.js

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.fitText = function( kompressor, options ) {

    // Setup options
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
        settings = $.extend({
          'minFontSize' : Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
          'maxFontSize' : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        }, options);

    return this.each(function(){

      // Store the object
      var $this = $(this); 

      // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
      var resizer = function () {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };

      // Call once to set.
      resizer();

      // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
      $(window).on('resize', resizer);
    });

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Can you please put the references somewhere?

Comment: Hello! What references do you mean?

Comment: The fittext, letteringjs, textillate, etc... `:)`

Comment: please check your question. I updated the fiddle. Does it work?

Comment: Hi man! I have no idea how to run it now :D

Comment: Click on `Run Snippet`.